# SortableJS: how to sort when a drag operation ends?

Tags: sortablejs

I'm using a library [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable?tab=readme-ov-file#readme) to sort a list.
By default, sorting is performed immediately when dragging.
Сan I change this behavior and do the sorting when the dragging is finished?

```
new Sortable(list, {
     animation: 150,
     draggable: '.draggable-item',
     forceFallback: true,
     fallbackOnBody: true,
})
```